# DOORS Date of Object Deletion

Tags: object, ibm-doors

Is it possible to find the date a DOORS Object was deleted?
I have checked the attributes and found one for creation and update but not delete.

Comment: I sort of wonder how a truly deleted object could have any attributes :-o Perhaps you might want to consider recording the deletion by adding a row to an ‘object deletion’ module, or by producing output to a text file?

Comment: A deleted Object remains in the module (I'm not talking about a purged Object here of course) and can be un-deleted hence I would have hoped that the history would have recorded the deletion somehow via a 'deleted date' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to answer so late - I've only just seen this. However, for anyone still looking for a solution - the deletion of an object is not recorded in an attribute, only as a history record for the object.

The simple script below is designed to run in a DXL attribute (which must be of type String, or Text). For deleted objects, it will record the date of deletion (if since last baseline), or a fixed message if the deletion was in a previou baseline of the module. The script could be modified easily to display its result in a DXL column.

With a little more effort, (and at the risk of degrading DOORS performance in use), it could be further modified to retrieve deletion date and time from previous module baselines.

```
History     hr   = null
HistoryType ht   = null
Date        dDel = null

if (!isDeleted(obj))
{
    obj.attrDXLName = ""
}
else
{
    for hr in obj do
    {
        ht = hr.type
        if (ht == deleteObject)
        {
            dDel = dateAndTime(hr.date)
        }
    }

    if (null dDel)
    {
        obj.attrDXLName = "Object deleted in a previous baseline."
    }
    else
    {
        obj.attrDXLName = "Object deleted: " dDel ""
    }
}
```